# VMware Fusion on MacBook Pro running Vista, not working after installing a wireless card

Tags: mac, windows-vista, wireless-networking, vmware-fusion, uninstall

A tech friend installed VMware on my Mac so I could use my Windows programs as well.  It worked great until I inserted my Sierra 881 USB wireless card while in VMware trying to get to the internet while on the road.  It worked briefly, then the AT&T Communication manager won't respond when you click on the icon, I can't open Network and Sharing center, I can't sync my palm - shows it can't connect.  Looks like it messed up several things, along with not being able to connect to the internet while in windows.  This wireless cards works directly from the Mac - but I need internet while in Windows for some work I am doing.  How do I uninstall this - when I try - it just gives me an endless reloading circle - not doing anything.  I really need to sync my palm and get back to the way it was.  I don't know much about VMware at all and I don't have access to my friend right now to get help.

Comment: Change the VM network settings to "Share the Mac's network connection (NAT)" then it would work like ethernet. So you should be able to just connect to the internet on your Mac and use internet on Windows as if a cable is plugged in

Answer (score 0):

try this its for an 885 ...sounds like it might work for the 881 tell me if it does!
                       mh

http://www.mac-forums.com/forums/other-hardware-peripherals/168290-t-usb-modem-problem-10-6-64bit.html